# Android: Button click error

Tags: android

I have been trying to write an android random quiz as part of my individual project at a programming school however I have been stuck for 2 weeks .I need to add code that allows me to move to the next question I have tried various methods with no success. Here is my code:

```
package favouredlee.com.virtualclassroom;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.media.session.MediaSessionCompat;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Random;


        public class VirtualClassroomActivity extends Activity {
        private QuizBook mQuizBook = new QuizBook();
        private ColorsBrand mColorsBrand = new ColorsBrand();
        TextView showQuizLabel;
        TextView questionView;
        Button button2;
    EditText inputText;
    Button button;


    QuizBook quizBook = new QuizBook();
    String delims = "[/]";



       @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_virtual_classroom);

        //Declare our questionView variables and assign the Views from the  layout file
        showQuizLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showQuizLabel);
        questionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.View);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        inputText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        String quiz = quizBook.getQuiz();
        final String[] tokens = quiz.split(delims);
        final String question = tokens[0];
        final String answer = tokens[1];



        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        showQuizLabel.setText("Question: " + question);




        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout =     (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void on Click(View v) {

// update showQuizLabel with our dynamic quiz

                int color = mColorsBrand.getColorsBrand();
                relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(color);
                button2.setTextColor(color);

                String userInput = inputText.getText().toString();
                if (answer.toLowerCase().equalsIgnoreCase(userInput)) {

                    showQuizLabel.setText("Congratulations");
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mQuizBook.getQuiz();




                } else {
                    showQuizLabel.setText("Bummer!");
                    button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
    enter code here


            }
        };


        button2.setOnClickListener(listener);
        button.setOnClickListener(listener);



    }

    public void nxtQuestion(){
        String quiz = quizBook.getQuiz();
        final String[] tokens = quiz.split(delims);
        final String question = tokens[0];
        final String answer = tokens[1];

        button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        int color = mColorsBrand.getColorsBrand();
        button2.setTextColor(color);

        String userInput = inputText.getText().toString();

        showQuizLabel.setText("Question: " + question);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Onclick() method do this..

```
 @Override
        public void on Click(View v)
 {
    switch(v.getId())
     {
      case R.id.button2:

       break;
      case R.id.button:

       break;

     }
}
```